# Jetpack compose build gitlab pipeline memory

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm building an android app using jetpack compose and I'm using my school's gitlab. The runner have only 4GB of memory and every time my pipeline fails on: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly. Is it normal that android project build needs more than 4GB of memory, or am I doing something wrong?

These plugins are in root build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("org.sonarqube") version "4.4.1.3373"
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.50" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.0-1.0.13" apply false
}
```

These plugins are in app/build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.9.22"
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}
```

And these are the dependencies I use:

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:$androidCoreVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$androidxLifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:$activityComposeVersion")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")
    // navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navigationComposeVersion")
    // Ktor http client
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
    // Dagger hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$daggerHiltVersion")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:$hiltNavigationComposeVersion")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerHiltVersion")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$daggerHiltVersion")

    // permission
    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:$accompanistPermissionsVersion")
    // arrow kt
    implementation("io.arrow-kt:arrow-core:$arrowKtVersion")
    implementation("io.arrow-kt:arrow-fx-coroutines:$arrowKtVersion")
    // security
    implementation("androidx.security:security-crypto:$androidSecurityCryptoVersion")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:$kotlinxDatetimeVersion")

    // bonsai - for tree view
    implementation("cafe.adriel.bonsai:bonsai-core:$bonsaiVersion")
```

I have tried both KAPT and KSP without much difference.
I have even tired doing optimisations from: https://developer.android.com/build/optimize-your-build

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configuration-cache=true
org.gradle.caching=true
android.useAndroidX=true
kotlin.code.style=official
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.enableJetifier=false
```

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy

stages:
  - build

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "34"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "34.0.0"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "11076708"

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - .gradle/
    - app/build/

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget unzip zip
  - export ANDROID_HOME="${PWD}/android-sdk-root"
  - install -d $ANDROID_HOME
  - wget --no-verbose --output-document=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}_latest.zip
  - unzip -q -d "$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools" "$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools.zip"
  - mv -T "$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools" "$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools"
  - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
  - sdkmanager --version
  - yes | sdkmanager --licenses > /dev/null || true
  - sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}"
  - sdkmanager "platform-tools"
  - sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}"
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

assembleDebug:
  interruptible: true
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
    - mv app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk housekeeper.apk
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
      - housekeeper.apk
      - build/
```

My project have roughly 20 screens. Am I doing something wrong or is it normal for build to need more than 4GB? And the runner just needs more memory. On normal gitlab where the runner have 8GB the pipepilne succeed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very much normal for Java pipelines.

For example, you can toggle the memory in [k8s runners like this](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes/#overwrite-container-resources):

```yaml
assembleDebug:
  variables:
   KUBERNETES_MEMORY_REQUEST: "6Gi"
   KUBERNETES_MEMORY_LIMIT: "8Gi"
```